# How i can find error iTunes connect

Tags: ios, cordova, crash

I am development one program with Cordova 2.1.0 for iOS, bur when this app have been reviewed Apple found that your app crashed on iPhone 5 and iPad (3rd Generation) running iOS 6.0.1, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

The crash is this, but i don't know how find the error in this crash and how solucionated the crash

```
Incident Identifier: D118AC06-AE7A-45FC-B006-480445F1AEE7
CrashReporter Key:   61fff04272e67e35a7d37d24f9e047e4b111fe0c
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:         Coto [4429]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/CE1C6A84-01B4-4324-B2E7-60F28C05B03A/Coto.app/Coto
Identifier:      Coto
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2012-12-11 16:43:37.661 -0800
OS Version:      iOS 6.0.1 (10A523)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x3427c29e 0x3af5e97a 0x3427fe02 0x3427e52c 0x341d5f64 0x3506c 0x8784 0x39fab588 0x39febd6c 0x39fe7ae0 0x3a0291c4 0x8454 0x39fecacc 0x39fec656 0x39fe483e 0x39f8cc34 0x39f8c6c8 0x39f8c116 0x3770859e 0x377081ce 0x3425116e 0x34251112 0x3424ff94 0x341c2eb8 0x341c2d44 0x39fe3478 0x39fe02f4 0x8092 0x806c)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x331a6350 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aefd11e pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3af3996e abort + 90
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39106d4a abort_message + 70
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39103ff4 default_terminate() + 20
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3af5ea74 _objc_terminate() + 144
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39104078 safe_handler_caller(void (*)()) + 76
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39104110 std::terminate() + 16
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x39105594 __cxa_rethrow + 84
9   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3af5e9cc objc_exception_rethrow + 8
10  CoreFoundation                  0x341c2f1c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
11  CoreFoundation                  0x341c2d44 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 100
12  UIKit                           0x39fe3478 -[UIApplication _run] + 664
13  UIKit                           0x39fe02f4 UIApplicationMain + 1116
14  Coto                            0x00008092 0x6000 + 8338
15  Coto                            0x0000806c 0x6000 + 8300

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x331a6d98 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aed4cf6 _pthread_workq_return + 14
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aed4a12 _pthread_wqthread + 362
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x3aed48a0 start_wqthread + 4
```

Comment: Did they send you a crash file, not just a text log?  If so, you should be able to symbolocate it with your (hopefully) archived version of the app you submitted

Comment: i don't understand you

Comment: How were you notified of the rejection?  Did you get an email?  If so, was there an attachment, or did you just get this crash log as plain text?

Comment: Open your Xcode organizer. Select the Devices tab, then choose "Device Logs" on the top left. Drag the crash report in there, this will symbolicate the crash report and you'll see what your was doing when the app crashed. Post the updated crash report in here if you don't know how to proceed after doing this.

Comment: Thanks very much Kerni for your explication. I don't see re-symbolicate the crash have changed but , i continue investigate